# Firebase: set reminders automatically from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am developing an android app using firebase. I want to create an event that will automatically remind the user base on user deadline date input choice. For example: user input date from:? to:? and date will be stored into firebase database and user will be receiving reminders until the deadline end. Is there anyway to set an automatic notification from the firebase server? Can anyone point me to the right direction. thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you mean automatic push notification from server, sure it can be done easily with cloud functions and cron jobs. There are many ways to do it

Method 1 :

First, create cloud function with `http event` to check which event will need to be remindered. And do push notification using FCM token of the user.

Second, make a cron job that call that function daily, or hourly. See detail example [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/delete-unused-accounts-cron) for more explanations.

Method 2 :

Same with above, but using `pub-sub event`. And the cron job using google app engine. The step by step guide, can be found [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/how-to-schedule-cron-jobs-with-cloud.html)

Comment: Thanks for poiting me to the write direction! I'm going through different tutorials to give me a better understand on how to write an event that will trigger the date in my firebase database also didn't fully understand how to write a notification using firebase function as I'm new using firebase. Can you help me to get a better understand on how it actually works in doing real code? Cheers